# How can I simplify this further (or can I?)

Tags: calculus, parametric

I am working through a parametrization problem and I have got to

$(ab \cos t \sin t) \sqrt{a^2 \sin^2t+b^2 \cos^2t}$

Is there any way I can simplify this using identities or other menthod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to integrate this expression you can substitute $u=\cos2t$ or $u=\sin^2t$ or $u=\cos^2t$ and the resulting integral is elementary.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on that ,what are working on ...?
but for example if I want to do an integral with this ,I will use :
$$Y=a \sin t ,x=a \cos t \to $$ so $(ab \cos t \sin t) \sqrt{a^2 \sin^2t+b^2 \cos^2t}=xy\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

or this idea 
$$(ab \cos t \sin t) \sqrt{a^2 \sin^2t+b^2 \cos^2t}=\frac{1}{2}(ab  \sin 2t) \sqrt{a^2 (\frac{1-\cos 2t}{2})+b^2 (\frac{1+\cos 2t}{2})}$$

Comment: If i'm ilntegrating %dt% how do I then change my integral in terms of the X and Y in your first bit?

Comment: What is your question , would you  post it here ?

Comment: I want to integrate the function I gave $dt$

Comment: So $/int(abcostsint)/sqrt{a^2sin^2t+b^2cos^2t}$

Comment: $\int(abcostsint)\sqrt{a^2sin^2t+b^2cos^2t}$

Comment: As far as I know , there is no close form solution for this integral type .you can solve it numerically.